# Make it even shorter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refactor my code and make it as simple as possible.
So is it possible to make the following even shorter?

```
let selectedSprintId = ((this.convertedSprintsToArray) [this.item.sprints[0].id] || '')
let endSelected = selectedSprintId && selectedSprintId.id;
```

the variables are like follow:

```
this.item.sprints[0] = {
    id: 1
    name: 'My Sprint'
}


this.convertedSprintsToArray = [{
  1: {
        id: 1
        name: 'My Sprint'
     },
  2: {
        id: 2
        name: 'My Second Sprint'
     },
}]
```

Comment: You can remove the parentheses. Also, the suffix `ToArray` on the array variable name doesn't add meaning or improve readability. The plural `convertedSprints` is sufficiently meaningful. Also, it appears as though `selectedSprintId` actually referrers to a `sprint` and not its `id` although that is context dependent.

Comment: Well, there is a reason for the namings. this is just a part of a bigger vuejs app. i ment the programming logic not the naming logic.

Comment: I know but there isn't much logic. You could factor `this` out with `const { convertedSprintsToArray, item: { sprints:[{ id }] } } = this;` ;)